# If no search result, then add item

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

In my android app I have a search screen.
The content is stored in a database, and a listview is populated via a ListAdapter.

This all works correct.
But I want the following functionality.

When a user searches, but gets no result, I would like to give him/her the option to add the search item.

for example:

list in listadapater is: [monkey, donkey, mouse]

when the user searches for: lion, he will see no results.
But I want the option to add lion to the database list.

Hopefully someone can get me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance,
Goldhorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add the new item into the database. Then you requery the database for a new cursor which you then pass to the adapter.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the step to requery for a new cursor in my train of thoughts ;-)